# Suppressing Warning from as.function() in R

Tags: r

In R I am using the mpoly package to define functions, a minimal example with output is

```
> library(mpoly)
> b_1=as.function(bernstein(1,1))
f(.) with . = x
```

Ideally I would like to run this function so that there is no output (note the output is in red in the console, the same colour as a warning) of

```
f(.) with . = x
```

I have tried to no avail the following

```
> b_1=suppressWarnings(as.function(bernstein(1,1)))
> b_1=invisible(as.function(bernstein(1,1)))

> options(warn=-1)
> b_1 = as.function(bernstein(1,5))
> options(warn=0)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
b_1=as.function(bernstein(1,1),silent=TRUE)
```